# VueJS Template Within Blade not Updated

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Vue Version: 2.6 
Laravel Version: 5.4

I have VueJS DOM with :disabled flag within laravel blade file(laravel mix), main data contain, images object like code below:

```
data() {
  return {
    images: {}
  }
}
```

then below is piece of button source code:

```
<button :disabled="!images.pict0" @click="showPict('pict0')">
 Show Image
</button>
```

Communication: Asynchronous

Problem:
when asynchronous data came, those button has still disabled, even when watch images object data has changed but those button still disabled.

Solving step has tried and failed:

- set images object with Vue.set, my assumption maybe caused by object reactivity in vue + combine with this.$forceUpdate()
- add boolean flag, hope when data came those boolean value set to false, then button has enabled,
- adding `<template></template>` tag surrounding those button

Hope got solution, thanks

Comment: Can you show me how the complete `images: {}` data after succesfully retriving data?

Comment: it contains key with uri string value ex. pict0: "https://stackoverflow.com/logo.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create logic to manipulate button element (DOM).

<button :disabled="isDisabled()" @click="showPict('pict0')">

```
isDisabled() {
 // the conditions to make your button unable/disable
}
```

**alternative use $refs to set your button value inside isDisabled()*

<button ref="imagesBtn :disabled="isDisabled()" @click="showPict('pict0')">

ex inside function:

```
this.$refs.imagesBtn.disable = true/false
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, enable / disable depend on uri of pict0, i'd try both way above, still not worked.

Answer (score 0):

#Updated

Issue has happened if caused by error on other part. I'd detected when data has not gotten yet, i event on some component, then i try click it to indicate render still running, but when has data gotten & error triggered, event which i clicked has stopped.

Thanks for your answer [Ihsan Fajar Ramadhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11561888/ihsan-fajar-ramadhan) & [Argo Raden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11915861/argo-raden)